# JavaFX Gluon Progress Indicator using charm-glisten.jar For Desktop Application

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I'm Trying to create a desktop application with circular progress indicator upon using gluon circular progress indicator using charm-glisten.jar file in scene builder I get InvocationTargetException while on using standard javafx-10 progress indicator it shows no Exception any suggestions ?.

Java Code:

```
package application;
    
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.ProgressIndicator;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;


public class Main extends Application 
{
    private double xOffset = 0;
    private double yOffset = 0;
    
    @FXML
    ProgressIndicator pg;
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) 
    {
        try 
        {
            primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
            AnchorPane root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Test1.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,600,400);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            scene.setFill(javafx.scene.paint.Color.TRANSPARENT);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            
            primaryStage.show();
            
            root.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() 
            {
                public void handle(MouseEvent e)
                {
                    xOffset = e.getSceneX();
                    yOffset = e.getSceneY();
                    
                }
            });
            
            root.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() 
            {
                public void handle(MouseEvent e) 
                {
                    primaryStage.setX(e.getScreenX() - xOffset);
                    primaryStage.setY(e.getScreenY() - yOffset);
                }
            });
            
        }
        catch(Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

FXML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.ProgressIndicator?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" style="-fx-background-color: #3D4956;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.Main">
   <children>
      <ProgressIndicator fx:id="pg" layoutX="196.0" layoutY="86.0" radius="100.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Error:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/javafx/css/converters/SizeConverter
    at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.ProgressIndicator.<clinit>(SourceFile:81)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.ReflectAccess.newInstance(ReflectAccess.java:166)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newInstance(ReflectionFactory.java:404)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:591)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1019)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:754)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2722)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2552)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2466)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3237)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3194)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3163)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3136)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3113)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3106)
    at application.Main.start(Main.java:30)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.javafx.css.converters.SizeConverter
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 29 more
Exception running application application.Main
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpUfE.png)

Comment: For starters, you are using a commercial library. What version are you using? 5.0.2 or lower are for Java 1.8, while 6.0.0 or higher are for Java 11.

Comment: I'm using Java 10 and charm-glisten-4.4.1.jar

Comment: Probably 6.0.5 will work for you.

Comment: Any link where to download the jar file

Comment: See this sample: https://github.com/gluonhq/client-samples/tree/master/Maven/HelloGluon, on how to use it. You can run it on desktop or mobile (Android/iOS).

Comment: Any Idea for other third party libraries that offer circular progress indicators

Comment: This one is OSS and follows Material Design: https://github.com/HanSolo/CircularProgressIndicator.

Comment: I used charm-glisten.jar version from 4.4.1 to 6.0.5 none of them are working for jdk 10 giving same exception any suggestions

Comment: I doubt you get same exception with 6.0.5. It is compiled against Java 11, so you will get a different error, because running with JDK 10 is not supported. Any reason to stick to a superseded JDK??

Comment: I'm using Java 10 because I'm also using Jfoenix jar file due to which if I use JDK 13 then it's JFXTextField when used throws exception saying something like skin is private component and no other  new version of Jfoenix has been released after jdk 10 to eliminate that exception